# Docs for Vim Omnicomplete key bindings

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

is there a webpage with key bindings (C-x C-o, etc.) for Omnicomplete in Vim?  Can't seem to find it online.

Comment: C-x is for insert mode. The convention for searching insert mode maps is to prefix the search with `i_`  For example: `:help i_ctrl-x` will lead you to the right place in help. Or `:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-o`

Answer (score 2):

Why search for it online if you have it locally?

```
:help ins-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, toiletfreak: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-completion